# Spring hibernate query help

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

currently I am using the following to pull rows from a table called `Table`:

```
return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Table");
```

How do I use hibernate to pull only the first *n* rows from the table (i.e. like a mySql `limit` would do)?

Thanks.

**Update:** so is this the proper way to do it?

```
getHibernateTemplate().setMaxResults(35);
return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Table");
```

Comment: It would be better to use a hibernate Query object to do the load and then set the max results on that. Problem with doing what you suggest is that it will be set on the hibernate template and that object is re-used. So the limit will be set for other queries as well.

Comment: I looked into this, what about using Criteria to acheive this?  What would be the benefits / downsides to using Criteria over Query object? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Hibernate [Criteria](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) query to do this and it works properly. I made use of the `setFirstResult()` and `setLastResults()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use HIbernateTemplate `setMaxResults` to limit the results.

Comment: Is the code that I updated in my question the proper way to do it?